# Proof that the limit of $a^{1/n}$ is one where $a>0$ is a real number and $n$ is a natural number

Tags: limits, analysis

> Proof that the limit of $a^{1/n}$ is one where $a$ is a real number and $n$ is a natural number.

I am only allowed to use $N,\epsilon$-Proof and the Squeeze theorem. For some special cases like $a$ is a natural numeber I could show that this is true but I couldn't show the general case.

Comment: What have you tried? And shouldn't you also require $a>0$?

Comment: sorry yes of corse

Comment: If you can prove it for any natural number, then you can use the squeeze theorem to prove it for any $a \geq 1$.

Comment: So you could prove it for natural $a$. Then use $$
1 \le a^{1/n}  \le (\left\lceil a \right\rceil )^{1/n} 
$$ for $a\geq 1$ and then use $$
a^{1/n}  = \frac{1}{{(1/a)^{1/n} }}
$$ for $0<a<1$.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense. Im blind lol

Comment: The simplest would be to check the log of $a^{1/n}$ tends ro $0$.